# Drawing a random sample when population data is split across multiple tables

Tags: sampling

I need to draw a stratified random sample from a dataset that is split across three databases.  Will the following approach create a random sample?

The data need to come from between two dates and are stratified by a yes/no flag.

The data is split according to its date: before some date it will be in DB-1 while on or after it will be in DB-2.  It is not possible to first combine the two datasets as they are too big to extract in their entirety.  My solution here is to assign a random value from 0 to 1 to all rows in both datasets.  Since each value is independent, I assume I can draw those rows with some a value below some threshold and it will be the same as though I had concatenated the two datasets and drawn a sample from that.

The yes/no flag is in a third database DB-FLAG.  One strata needs the rows to have a yes, while the other needs it to have a no.  I have no way of knowing which it will be until I have already extracted the data from DB-1 and DB-2.  My solution is to draw more records than I think I will need, sort them by random number, and proceed to check the yes/no value until I have reached the sample size I need.

Do you see any problems with this approach?   Or any alternatives come to mind?

For reference, here's a sample of the tables I'm using.

DB-1 / DB-2

| ID | random_number | keep (TRUE if <= 0.1) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 0.4 | FALSE |
| 02 | 0.1 | TRUE |
| 03 | 0.6 | FALSE |
| 04 | 0.1 | TRUE |

DB-FLAG

| ID | flag (yes/no) |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | no |
| 02 | yes |
| 03 | yes |
| 04 | no |

Answer (score 2):

What you've described is a variant of two-phase sampling for stratification (also called double sampling for stratification). Your procedure will work, but can be simplified. Adding a random number to every row in the databases is unnecessary.

Any sensible database program will be able to tell you the total number of rows in the database, even if the data is too large to compute summary statistics on. Let N1 be the number of rows in DB-1 and N2 the number in DB-2. Let N = N1+N2

The standard way to perform two-phase sampling for stratification would be to select n observations from N. This is easy by drawing a sample from the numbers 1 to N. Then we look up the strata indicators for those n observations, and find we have n_yes rows with yes and n_no rows with no. Finally we take m_yes observations randomly sampled from n_yes and m_no observations randomly sampled form n_no. This gives us the desired sample of m_yes and m_no individuals.

Your proposed procedure of randomly ordering the n rows and then taking the first m_yes yes's and m_no no's is equivalent to this way of taking a sample.

But, the formulas for estimating the mean and variance are slightly different for two-phase sampling for stratification compared to ordinary stratified sampling. For example see Lohr Chapter 12.2 or Scheaffer et al 5.11. In particular, if you don't already know the true proportion of yes and no in DB-FLAG, then you will need to estimate it. This can be done by the normal way of two-phase sampling, but I don't think your procedure would be able to estimate the proportion without extra work.